# kubernetes python watch stream

Tags: python, api, kubernetes, watch

I'm trying to start watch events:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if 'CLUSTER' in os.environ:
        config.load_incluster_config()
    else:
        config.load_kube_config()
    api_client = client.CertificatesV1beta1Api()
    print("INFO:    Waiting for event to come up...")
    w = watch.Watch()
    for event in w.stream(api_client.list_certificate_signing_request, pretty=api_pretty):
        certificate = event["object"]
        spec_name = event["object"].metadata.name
        spec_groups = event["object"].spec.groups
        spec_username = event["object"].spec.username
        print("INFO:    Handling %s on %s" % (event["type"], spec_name))
        ...someOtherStuffs
```

Locally everything is going well, but when I'm trying run this code inside a cluster - it doesn't watch to a new event.

Can somebody put me in to the right direction?

P.S I tried to use `watch=True` into stream. Timeout just stop the pod. Timeout with `while True:` working, but I think it's not a good way

Comment: are you able to [watch Pods](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/6.0.0#example) or something other than `Certificates`? I would also suggest [`config.debug = True`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/6.0.0/kubernetes/client/configuration.py#L153) and see if it surfaces anything interesting

Comment: It working with
     w = watch.Watch()
     for event in w.stream(v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces, watch=True):
         print(event["object"])

But with `list_certificate_signing_request, watch=True` - doesn't :(

Comment: "doesn't" what? Returns instantly? Waits forever? Does `kubectl get csr -w` return events but python doesn't?

Comment: So sorry, it's my fault. I expected that my application logs will be output through `kubectl logs -f` and when they weren't - I was confused. I thought that my application didn't see new event... Passing `-u` option to run python command resolve this issue. So sorry again